How to Use React Native with OpenAI's Whisper Module for Speech-to-Text from Firebase Storage?
I'm trying to get speech-to-text with the whisper module from OpenAI. The audio file has been saved in firebase storage. It works when I try to transcribe the file locally, however, when I try to get the file from Firebase storage it doesn't work.
This is my code:
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import {Audio} from 'expo-av';
import {storage} from './firebaseConfig';
import {getDownloadURL, listAll, ref, uploadBytes} from 'firebase/storage';
import OpenAI from "openai";
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";
 
 
 
const RecordingStatuses = {
    IDLE: 'idle', RECORDING: 'recording', PAUSED: 'paused',
};
 
const App = () => {
    const [recording, setRecording] = useState(null);
    const [recordingStatus, setRecordingStatus] = useState(RecordingStatuses.IDLE);
    const [audioPermission, setAudioPermission] = useState(false);
    const [recordingsList, setRecordingsList] = useState([]);
    const [showRecordingsList, setShowRecordingsList] = useState(false);
    const openai = new OpenAI({apiKey: 'sk-xxx'});
 
 
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const {granted} = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
            console.log('Permission Granted:', granted);
            setAudioPermission(granted);
        })();
    }, []);
 
    const startRecording = useCallback(async () => {
        if (!audioPermission || recordingStatus !== RecordingStatuses.IDLE) return;
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            allowsRecordingIOS: true, playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        });
 
        const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();
        await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY);
        await newRecording.startAsync();
        setRecording(newRecording);
        setRecordingStatus(RecordingStatuses.RECORDING);
    }, [audioPermission, recordingStatus]);
 
    const pauseRecording = useCallback(async () => {
        if (recordingStatus === RecordingStatuses.RECORDING && recording) {
            await recording.pauseAsync();
            setRecordingStatus(RecordingStatuses.PAUSED);
        }
    }, [recordingStatus, recording]);
 
    const stopRecording = useCallback(async () => {
        if (recordingStatus === RecordingStatuses.RECORDING && recording) {
            await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
            const uri = recording.getURI(); // Lokale bestandspad
            await uploadAudioToStorage(uri); // Nieuwe functie om audio te uploaden
            setRecording(null);
            setRecordingStatus(RecordingStatuses.IDLE);
        }
    }, [recordingStatus, recording]);
 
    async function uploadAudioToStorage(uri) {
        try {
            const datumNu = new Date();
            const tijdDatum = datumNu.getTime();
            const filename = `Zorgplan_${tijdDatum}.mp3`;
            const storageRef = ref(storage, `Opnames/${filename}`);
            const blob = await fetch(uri).then(r => r.blob());
            await uploadBytes(storageRef, blob, {contentType: 'audio/mp3'});
            const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
            console.log('File available at', downloadUrl);
 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error uploading file and creating document:", error);
        }
    }
 
 
    const fetchRecordingsFromStorage = async () => {
        // Verondersteld dat `storage` correct is geïnitialiseerd in je firebaseConfig.
        const listRef = ref(storage, 'Opnames/');
        listAll(listRef)
            .then(async (res) => {
                const urls = await Promise.all(res.items.map((itemRef) => getDownloadURL(itemRef)));
                console.log(urls); // Dit zijn de URLs naar je bestande n
                setRecordingsList(urls.map((url, index) => ({url, id: index, filename: `Opname ${index + 1}`}))); // Opslaan in de staat
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error fetching storage listings", error);
            });
    };
 
 
    const handleTranscribe = async (recordingUrl) => {
       console.log('Transcribing URL:', recordingUrl); // Verifieer of de URL correct wordt gelogd
    if (!recordingUrl) {
        console.error("Geen geldige URL doorgegeven aan handleTranscribe");
        return;
    }
    await transcribeAudio(recordingUrl);
    }
 
 
 
/*    async function transcribeAudio(recordingUrl) {
        let fileToRead = '';
    const transcription = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
    file: RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(recordingUrl, "base64"),
    model: "whisper-1",
  });
 
  console.log(transcription.text);
}
*/
    async function transcribeAudio(recordingUrl) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                model: "whisper-1",
                file: recordingUrl }),
        });
        const transcription = await response.json();
        console.log("Transcription result:", transcription);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error transcribing audio:", error);
    }
}
 
 
    /******************************DIT IS HTML VAN DE APP*******************************************************/
 
    return (<View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>...</Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
                fetchRecordingsFromStorage();
                setShowRecordingsList(!showRecordingsList);
            }}
        >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Laad Opnames</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {showRecordingsList && (<ScrollView style={styles.recordingsList}>
            {recordingsList.map((recording, index) => (<View key={index} style={styles.recordingItem}>
                <Text style={styles.recordingText}>{recording.filename}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => handleTranscribe(recording.url)}
                    style={{marginLeft: 10}}
                >
                    <Icon name="microphone" size={30} color="#007bff"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>))}
        </ScrollView>)}
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.microphoneButton]} onPress={startRecording}>
            <Icon name="microphone" size={30} color="#FFF"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {(recordingStatus === 'recording' || recordingStatus === 'paused') && (<View style={styles.playbackControls}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={stopRecording} style={styles.controlButton}>
                <Icon name="stop" size={30} color="#FFF"/>
                <Text style={styles.controlText}>Opslaan</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={recordingStatus === 'recording' ? pauseRecording : startRecording}
                style={styles.controlButton}
            >
                <Icon name={recordingStatus === 'recording' ? "pause" : "play"} size={30} color="#FFF"/>
                <Text
                    style={styles.controlText}>{recordingStatus === 'recording' ? "Pauzeren" : "Verder opnemen"}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>)}
    </View>);
};
 
 
/******************************DIT IS CSS VAN DE APP*******************************************************/
 
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between',
    }, headerContainer: {
        marginTop: 50, alignItems: 'center',
    }, header: {
        fontSize: 32, fontWeight: 'bold',
    }, button: {
        backgroundColor: '#007bff', borderRadius: 20, padding: 10, marginVertical: 10, alignSelf: 'center',
    }, buttonText: {
        color: '#FFF', textAlign: 'center',
    }, recordingsList: {
        marginTop: 20, width: '100%',
    }, recordingItem: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#CCC',
    }, recordingText: {
        color: '#000',
    }, microphoneButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff4757', borderRadius: 50, padding: 20, position: 'absolute', right: 20, bottom: 20,
    }, playbackControls: {
        flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 20,
    }, controlButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#007bff', borderRadius: 50, padding: 20, marginHorizontal: 20, alignItems: 'center',
    }, controlText: {
        color: '#FFF', marginTop: 8,
    },
});
 
 
export default App;
 

This is the error that I receive when I try to transcribe it:
Transcription result: {"error": {"code": null, "message": "1 validation error for Request
body -> file
  field required (type=value_error.missing)", "param": null, "type": "invalid_request_error"}}

Also, I've tried to use react native file system. In this case I want to add the import:
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";
I had the code for this but I ended up not using it since the import didn't work.
The error code that I received was this:
Cannot read property 'DocumentDir' of null.
Perhaps it's useless but if it's better than my current function please let me know how to fix this.

first thing I'd try is to save the file to the device stroage (see: react-native-fs, think this could be done with rn-fetch-blob too) then check that you can play the audio. if you cant the issue is likely in the upload if you can the issue is likely the download. determine which issue and update the question so we know where to troubleshoot. storing the file on the device for processing might just solve the problem in itself. code also suggestes you're passing a url to the open-ai module not the file itself.
